# How to say "To telephone"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is better if I mean '**to make a [tele]phone call**'?

> Tomorrow I have **to call** my doctor.

or

> Tomorrow I have **to call to** my doctor.

Are there any suggestions for a better way to express "to telephone" in this example?

Comment: The most common usage is "to call".  You could be more clear by saying "phone your doctor", but I don't believe I've ever heard "telephone" used as a verb.

Comment: It is idiomatic to say: _Tomorrow I have to call my doctor._ (without the preposition "to".) However, the preposition **is** idiomatic in _Tomorrow I have to **make a call to** my doctor._

Comment: It was used in BrE. You will often hear it in old British films, e.g. "I shall telephone the police."

Comment: I've heard "to telephone" used as a verb, but it does seem a little old-fashioned.  *to phone* is more modern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To call someone* is almost always assumed to mean making a telephone call to them.  It is by far the most common way to express making a telephone call.

> I called my parents last night.

*To call **to** someone* means to shout (or otherwise speak loudly) to them, usually because they are some distance away, and often specifically to get their attention.

> We called to them from the other side of the street.

*To call someone **to somewhere*** means to summon them, or ask them to come, to some place.

> She called me to her office to discuss what had happened.

*To call someone or something a name* is to refer to them by that name.

> Her name is MacKenzie, but her friends call her "Mac."

These are the first four definitions of *to call* [given here](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/call), and are probably the most common way the word is used.  They can be distinguished by what kinds of nouns are used (people, places, names) and whether and how "to" is used.  That page gives other definitions as well, but those can also be distinguished by the types of nouns and prepositions used.